# Excel VBA Commandbutton Switching Worksheet how to keep same viewarea

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some form control commandbuttons on my worksheet as navigation buttons for switching between worksheets, my issue is the navigation buttons are at the bottom of my worksheet and in the same place on every worksheet which you have to scroll down to, when switching the worksheet page the position changes to the very top, is there anyway to make it so when switching worksheets to copy the current active sheet/scollbar position and make it the same when I go to my next sheet.

the reason for this is so my navigation panel that I have created doesn't look like its moving between sheet changes

```
My current code is this

Sub Page2()

  Sheets("Page 2").Activate

End Sub
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be enough to have the macro select a certain cell that would place you at a certain scrollbar position? `Sheets("Page 2").cells(10, 10).Select` for instance.

Comment: It's one way I already thought off, I didn't want to have to select a cell to set the position, just for it to be in the same scroll position when switching sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method2:

```
Sub Page2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Page 2").Activate

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 20
'this will be superior; set this number to the row of your buttons or whatever

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This more like what I am after, it does work but it messes up it the user then chooses to switch sheets using the tabs at the bottom, is there any work around for this?

Comment: @Windmill this should do what you want now

Comment: currently 36, this still seems to have the same issue, whats happening if I use the commandbutton it switches sheets and scrolls down correctly If I then use the tabs to go back to my original sheet and use the commandbutton again it switches but scrolls further down, I think whats happening is its incrementing by the scroll down amount each time, could it when pressing the commandbutton reset the scroll amount first to the top then scroll down, I think that would fix it just not sure on the code. Cheers

Comment: @Windmill try what I just posted, but run it BEFORE you use anything. This will set all the sheets up to be settled on the command button site. DO NOT run it with the command button, it will scroll ALL your sheets down each time.

Comment: Or would it be better for you, like you just suggested, to have it simply reset and redo the scroll each time?

Comment: reset the scroll each time, but can I make it so its the commandbutton that does the reset then scroll?

Comment: @Windmill - I think I've found the best solution. You should be able to adapt this to each sheet, etc. If it works please select the answer haha

Comment: Method2 is exactly the code I was after in regards to my question. Many Thanks for you Help tannman357